# Kotlin: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in tests

Tags: gradle, nosuchmethoderror, kotlin, source-sets

Is it possible to use Kotlin package functions and package properties in different sourcesets? When I try to do so, I have `NoSuchMethodError` thrown.

---

**Example**

I have Gradle project with Kotlin code and two sourcesets in it, `main` and `test`.
In `main`, I have the following code in one of the files:

```
package ru.ifmo.ctddev.igushkin.dkvs
...
public val payloadSplitter: String = " ### "
```

In `test` I try to access `payloadSplitter` with the following code:

```
package ru.ifmo.ctddev.igushkin.dkvs
...
public class MessageTests {
    ...
    test fun testParsing() {
        ...
        checkParseAndToString("p1b 345 ${payloadSplitter} set a b c")
    }
    ...
}
```

And exactly in the first line where `payloadSplitter` is accessed, at runtime I get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: ru.ifmo.ctddev.igushkin.dkvs.DkvsPackage.getPayloadSplitter()Ljava/lang/String;
```

---

Other global variables and functions are also inaccessible in `test` with the same error.

---

**UPD** Kotlin team explained the issue and announced the fix [here](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2015/06/improving-java-interop-top-level-functions-and-properties/).

Comment: Do you have any top level functions/properties in ru.ifmo.ctddev.igushkin.dkvs package in tests?

Comment: How do you run the tests? Could you post your gradle config? It looks like the test package is compiled against the main package but is ran without it.

Comment: @SalomonBRYS, https://github.com/h0tk3y/dkvs/blob/master/build.gradle -- here it is.

Comment: @NataliaUkhorskaya, yes. I have a top level property. I'll try to remove it a little bit later.

Comment: @hotkey How do you run the tests ? Via an editor or via command line ? If the latter, which command ?

Comment: @NataliaUkhorskaya, thanks, I removed the package-level property from `test` and it started working. I suggest you posting an answer with this solution. I would also be happy to know what is the exact reason of such a strange behaviour.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

For properties and methods outside of classes, Kotlin creates a java class named ${packagename}Package with the properties and methods implemented as static methods and variables.  With multiple source-sets, the java class will be created twice, once for each source-set.  Your issue is that the test source-set "package class" is hiding the class compiled in the main source-set.

As mentioned in the comments above, avoid having any top-level properties or methods in the test source-set to prevent the Kotlin compiler from creating this package class in the test output directory.

Comment: Thanks. There's one more workaround which follows from what you said, I posted it as another answer.

Comment: Another side note to this solution; at least in Gradle, you need to run a clean build, or the test runner will still find the generated Package class.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to what was suggested earlier, I found another workaround: if you need package-level functions or properties in `test` just move the tests to different package, e.g. in your test sources:

```
 package ru.ifmo.ctddev.igushkin.dkvs.tests
```

and then do

```
 import ru.ifmo.ctddev.igushkin.dkvs.*
```

which is everything from your main package. This will make Kotlin compliler generate two non-conflicting Package classes, therefore both can have global members.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue when testing kotlin-native module, it was fixed by adding this dependencies:

```
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test:$kotlin_version"
testImplementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit:$kotlin_version"
```